# Where is sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

In learning about replication in SQL Server and having problems creating a subscription, I looked at the definition for sp_addsubscription. It calls sys.sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo, which I cannot find on the server. This stored procedure obviously exists, as it no errors occur regarding it not existing. Where does it live, and can its code be viewed?

Comment: check this out
http://www.g-productions.nl/index.php?name=sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo&version=2008RTM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after more research I found that sys.sp_MSrepl_getpublisherinfo lives in a database named mssqlsystemresource, which lives in Sql Server's binn folder. This database is invisible to SSMS, but you can copy and attach it as a different name to have full access. This process is described here:

http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/sqlserver/t21348-browse-mssqlsystemresource-mdf-sql-servers-resource-database.aspx

I have copied that text here, in case that page goes away in the future:

> Giving credit where credit is due, I found the following info I am
>   about to  post at the following location:
>
> http://web.archive.org/web/20150407042809/http://www.aspfaq.com/sql2005/show.asp?id=28
>
> Since the engine has hooks that hide the mssqlsystemresource database
>   from  users, you don't have direct access to it through the GUI.
>
> However, there is a way around this:
>
> 1. Determine where the system databse files live, and keep this path handy:
>
>    ```
>    USE master
>    GO
>    SELECT REPLACE(filename, 'master.mdf', '') 
>      FROM sys.sysfiles 
>     WHERE fileid = 1
>    ```
> 2. Stop the SQL Server service;
> 3. Copy the files mssqlsystemresource.*df -> resource_copy.*df.  NOTE: do *not* rename or remove the mssqlsystemresource files!
> 4. Start the SQL Server service;
> 5. Run the following code in a new query window:
>
>    ```
>    EXEC sp_attach_db 
>      'Resource_Copy', 
>      '<path from above>resource_copy.mdf', 
>      '<path from above>resource_copy.ldf'
>    ```
> 6. Now, the system will no longer identify this database as a "special"  database
> 7. You can easily scan through the names of system objects that might  otherwise be unknown (and browse any code associated with these
>      objects) from  a GUI (like SQL Server Management Studio).